# laravel verification email not being sent for api requests

Tags: email, laravel-10

I have a laravel project with react (for web) and react native (for mobile) front ends. If a user registers via the web (using Breeze), the verification email is sent properly, so I'm sure my mail settings are correct.

However, when the user registers via the api (or triggers a resend) the email never arrives. I can see it in the `Mail` section of the request in telescope, so I don't understand why it's not going.

controller method:

```php
    function register(Request $request) {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:'.User::class,
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
            'device_name' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);

        // event(new Registered($user));
        $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

        auth()->login($user);

        return [
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken
        ];
    }
```

As you can see, I've tried both `event(new Registered($user));` and `$user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();`. The mailable shows in both cases against the request in telescope, but it fails to reach the destination in both cases.

Does the api trigger mail via a different method than for web requests? How can I troubleshoot this further?

Comment: I've reproduced this in a minimal project with just breeze installed. Even if I point the registration request at the same controller method (RegisteredUserController/store), the same thing happens - correct registration with Mailer in telescope but nothing received, whereas it works via web.

Comment: I've also tried to test this with phpunit, but I get an error that `Method Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::assertNothingSent does not exist`, so that's not helping.